# How to route mails outside Mac Os X Server host

Tags: email, osx-server

I have a mac osx server at my office. I have only one email address configured on it because it's an email address outside my GSuite account. That email address was created for sending mails from a php script (I don't want to pay to Google for that email address because I don't need all of the Google Services on it). I configured PHP Mailer for sending mails using that email account.

It's connecting perfectly fine, authentication is correct, etc., but there is one problem: if I send mails to @mydomain.com it says that account doesn't exist, but it does exist, only that it is hosted on GSuite. If I send mails outside mydomain, it works fine.

Question is: how do I route those mails to look up for the correct MX récords? I mean, how to make those @mydomain.com emails reach the GSuite host?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple MX records per domain. It is possible. They will use priorities. You can even have multiple email servers checking emails from each other.

However, you case with hosted emails this won't work. Google is not going to let you do this.

You will have to pay.